# How come the chained dragons don't choke when they grow?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

I have a question regarding episode 1 of season 5 of Game of Thrones. In the final episode of season 4, Daenarys chains the dragons in the cave, and they are depicted as being medium sized, with the chains fitting them quite tightly. In the first episode of season 5, she visits them, and they are much larger! How did they not get choked by the small chains? Did anyone replace their chains? Could anyone really do that without being devoured?

Comment: **In the books**: the dragons are not nearly as large as the ones in the show, *plus* Viserion has shattered and melted through his chains and Rhaegal is not much further from doing so too. A bit more info [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60933/21267).

Comment: That is a very informative post there!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mix milk of poppy in their food and when they are asleep change the chains. Risky yes but might work.

> Milk of the poppy is a medical drink, used as both a painkiller and an anesthetic. Higher doses will induce unconsciousness, so patients can undergo surgery. Maesters make it from crushed poppy flowers and it has a white color, hence "milk of the poppy".

http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Milk_of_the_poppy

It should work since it is made from poppy flowers, it is similar to morphine and morphine works on animal.

Comment: Does milk of the poppy affect dragons? What are its effects anyway?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Nice! In universe answer.